# How to wrap (and shrink if needed) in column layout

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, responsive-design, angular-material

Lately I came across problem where Im trying to create three column layout where columns will be filled with dynamic number of divs (boxes) (around 5-15) with each having its own height according to its content.

These divs are supposed to:

1) Lay in column.

2) Wrap to next column whenever they reach viewport height.

3) When/if layout reaches three columns state and needs wrap again - shrink all columns/divs to still fit and not break the layout

Picture below ilustrates the [OUTCOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ad5v.png)

(So for example if #4 was a little bit shorter, it wouldnt wrap to third column but stay under #3 instead)

Tried to solve that playing with Angular Material 'layout-wrap' & 'layout='column' - however it will refuse to shrink divs horizontally when needed. So after a couple of wraps, further divs will jump out of container.

Flexbox seems to fail in this situation.

Perhaps I could do that in Link function via Angular?

Any guidance or tips will be **appreciated!**

Comment: Do you know that you can do this using bootstrap or pureCSS??

Comment: So what do u have so far? just an image? any attempts or effort?

Comment: CSS column-count might work for this.

Comment: take a look at http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be looking for the [GridList](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdGridList) component which contains tiles.

You can set it up to have different numbers of columns for different breakpoints so that smaller devices have only 1 column, whereas larger devices have 3.

Make sure to checkout the [demos](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList) as well to see how it can be used.